# Unity Method Won't call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I want to list rooms in my lobby.To do that I instantiate a prefab for joining the match in the method `OnRoomListUpdate()` but I've noticed that it isn't calling, even with several rooms created.

This is the code, as you can see it is very simple:

```
public override OnRoomListUpdate()
{

    print("RoomListUpdate Called);

    Instantiate(RoomPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

Comment: You gotta show us much more. Have you properly joined a lobby?

Comment: do you mean, with the method OnJoinedLobby()?

Comment: OnJoinedLobby isn't going to join a lobby for you, its called after you join a lobby

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant OnReceivedRoomListUpdate() ?

This is taken from [photon](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/lobby-and-matchmaking/matchmaking-and-lobby#matchmaking_checklist):

> While joined to a default lobby type, the client will receive periodic room list updates. PUN caches the rooms list and triggers the OnReceivedRoomListUpdate() callback everytime an update happens. That's when you can get the updated list of rooms using PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList().

Comment: But, the problema here is that I'm using Photon's PUN 2, and there's almost nothing of info about it.